# Add Vertices to a Tinkerpop graph (gremlin) by applying a function to a Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, serialization, gremlin, tinkerpop3

As the question indicates I have been trying for quite some time to code something that could read through a data frame and add vertices to a gremlin graph with properties extracted from the dataframe. For that purpose I wrote the following code:

```
val graph = TinkerGraph.open()

val g = graph.traversal

def myFunction(field1:String,field2:String) ={

    graph.addVertex(field1,field2)
 }


val df = List(
  (1,"A","X",1),
  (2,"B","X",2),
  (3,"B","X",3),
  (4,"D","X",4),
  (5,"E","X",5),
  (6,"A","Y",1),
  (7,"C","Y",2)
).toDF("id","value","group","ts")


df.map(row => myFunction("id1", row.getAs[String]("value")))
```

The problem is I keep getting the same error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2085)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.map(DataFrame.scala:1425)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57
```

I have read some questions/answers here and I came to the conclusion that the problem is that my function is getting "something" (*graph* and *g*) that is not serializable and, therefore, it fails.

What can I do to avoid this error? I have tried creating an object, defining my function inside (as you can see below) and calling the function outside with `test1.myFunction` but it still didn't work.

```
object test1  {

    val graph = TinkerGraph.open()

    val g = graph.traversal

def myFunction(field1:String,field2:String) ={

    graph.addVertex(field1,field2)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on discussion in comments. [Here](https://github.com/datastax/graph-examples/blob/master/entity-resolution/src/main/scala/com/datastax/bdp/er/EntityRecognitionExample.scala#L95-L125) is a working example for Datastax Graph TinkerPop implementation. Here is a sketch of the code base on [TinkerPop driver documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-java). Each spark partition is handled on one of the remote executors. Thus you should connect inside foreachPartition call to remote TP server and send data to it.

```
df.foreachPartition(rows => {
     Cluster cluster = Cluster.open(); 
     Client client = cluster.connect();
      for (row <- rows) {
          val params = Map ("field1" -> "id1",
           "field2", row.getAs[String]("value"))
          client.submit("graph.addVertex(field1,field2)", params.asJava).all()
      }
      cluster.close()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Code like this one has no place in Apache Spark.

Serialization issues are a secondary problem. Even if you resolved serialization issues, and use action like `foreach`, in place of transformation (`map`) Spark has no shared state.

Ignoring `local` mode, each executor uses its own JVM (and even physical host). There is no shared memory and the only communication with the driver is either with results of `runJob` or with `accumulators`. Both could be used here, but in this problem, there are as good (if not worse), as computing everything locally from the beginning.

A fundamental reading for you: [Understanding closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-).

Comment: By the way it is possible with gremlin server http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#starting-gremlin-server
In this case each spark executor will remotely connect to the server and add vertices to it over gremlin driver.
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-java

That is common pattern to work with real TinkerPop base databases not toy TinkerPop graphs. That is just reference single node in-memory implemeintation

Comment: I am trying to do somehow the same thing, I am loading file into DataFrame in Spark and I want to save it into my graph using Gremlin
I was considering using scala-gremlin connector  
  
@ArtemAliev `In this case each spark executor will remotely connect to the server and add vertices to it over gremlin driver. `  
->  How can I initialize a connection inside each worker ?  
  
@user837195 do you have an opinion on it ?